# How to return a char value from one method to another?

Tags: java

This is what I have...

```
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //variable declaration
      char letter;

      getLetter();

      letter = "";
      System.out.println(letter)
   }

   public static int getLetter()
   {
      String text;
      char letter;

      text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter.");
      letter = text.charAt(0);

      System.out.println(letter);

      return letter;
   }
}
```

I want to get the letter the user inputs from the method getLetter and transfer it in the main method where I can display it on the screen. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Start with an extremely basic java tutorial. One that explains data types and another that explains method invocations and their return types.

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: `letter = '(getLetter)'` requires a semi-colon, although it is not even a valid statement.  A `char` is a 255 bit ascii code, you have is a `String`, it should be within double quotes `" "`

Comment: simply `letter = getLetter();` baby and your method `getLetter()` should be `char` not `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getLetter()` method should return type `char` not `int`. This is because you have assigned the local variable `letter` as type `char`.

Also, methods are called by `method();` not `'(method)'`.

Try out the following code:

```
public class YourClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //variable declaration
    char letter;
    letter = getLetter();
    System.out.println(letter);
  }

  public static char getLetter() {
    String text;
    char letter;

    text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter.");
    letter = text.charAt(0);

  System.out.println(letter);
  return letter;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type for your method is an int, but you're returning a character. Your method invocation is incorrect as well; it should be:

```
 letter = getLetter(); // follows the same format as the declaration.
```

You should make use of the Java Tutorials, they can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/